# Ordered triplet query

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, diophantine-approximation

$$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 3xyz$$

How many ordered triples $(x,y,z)$ are there that satisfy the above equation.

are the only solutions $x=y=z=0$ and $1$?

Are there non trivial solutions?

I saw this problem in a friends textbook but cannot remember the name of it therefore cannot cite the the exact source.

Comment: Your suggestions do not solve the equations. If $x=0$ then necessarily $y=z=0$.

Comment: haha I only realised my mistake now, i was solving a different equation, apologies. so would the only solutions for this be x = y = z = 0 and 1

Comment: There are infinitely many solutions which you can generated by a procedure. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MarkovEquation.html see also http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MarkovNumber.html

Comment: This question may be helpful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94394/diophantine-equation-in-positive-integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $41$ solutions (this refers to the original problem statement that included the condition $-10<x,y,z<10$). If we additionally require $x\le y\le z$, there are only the following $10$:
$$[-5, -2, 1]\\
[-5, -1, 2]\\
[-2, -1, 1]\\
[-2, -1, 5]\\
[-1, -1, 1]\\
[-1, -1, 2]\\
[0, 0, 0]\\
[1, 1, 1]\\
[1, 1, 2]\\
[1, 2, 5]$$
Without the restriction $|x|,|y|,|z|<10$, a whole bunch of additional solutions comes up, e.g. $(5, 29, 433)$.

Comment: does ordered triplet mean x≤y≤z

Comment: Hm, if I wanted to identify $(1,2,5)$ with $(5,1,2)$, I'd say I count *unordered* triples and if I count them as different solutions I'd say I count *ordered* triples. Of course the former implicitly allows me to *impose* an order to my liking on the triple, so that may be confusing.