# History Question on Continued Fractions

Tags: math-history, continued-fractions

I worked out the periodicity of some infinite continued fractions last night by hand. (Don't ask me why)
For example,  $\sqrt{13}= [3,1,1,1,1,6,1,1,1,1,6,\ldots]$. Last night I worked out the first period of this continued fraction and the algebra was a little meh.
 I was wondering, what is the largest continued fraction period ever worked out by hand before?

For example:
$\sqrt{D}$ may have the continued fraction expansion: $[\text{repeat}(a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots, a_n)]$.
Define the "first period worked out by hand" to be:
The discovery of the first $a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_n$ of the infinite continued fraction $\sqrt{D}$ using nothing but pencil, and paper.

Any stories for me?

Comment: No story, but there are efficient ways to compute the continued fraction of square roots.

Comment: How is that related to math history?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lagrange's method uses just integer arithmetic and is suitable for use by hand. See [How to detect when continued fractions period terminates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90406/how-to-detect-when-continued-fractions-period-terminates/90565#90565)

If you need more detail let me know.

Note that I used precisely that in [Minimum of $n$? $123456789x^2 - 987654321y^2 =n$ ($x$,$y$ and $n$ are positive integers)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/344671/minimum-of-n-123456789x2-987654321y2-n-x-y-and-n-are-positive-i/443220#443220) although it was by computer.

Not by the way, if you are primarily interested in the square root of positive a integer $D,$ then the triple indicating a first form in the cycle is given by finding $$  a_0 = \lfloor \sqrt D \rfloor  $$ and then forming the triple $$ \langle 1, 2 a_0, a_0^2 - D \rangle $$

Here, the triple $ \langle a, b, c \rangle $ refers to the quadratic form $$ f(x,y) = a x^2 + b x y + c y^2.  $$ The form is "reduced" if both $ac <0$ and $b > |a+c|.$

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./Pell
Input n for Pell 
991

0  form   1 62 -30   delta  -2
1  form   -30 58 5   delta  12
2  form   5 62 -6   delta  -10
3  form   -6 58 25   delta  2
4  form   25 42 -22   delta  -2
5  form   -22 46 21   delta  2
6  form   21 38 -30   delta  -1
7  form   -30 22 29   delta  1
8  form   29 36 -23   delta  -2
9  form   -23 56 9   delta  6
10  form   9 52 -35   delta  -1
11  form   -35 18 26   delta  1
12  form   26 34 -27   delta  -1
13  form   -27 20 33   delta  1
14  form   33 46 -14   delta  -3
15  form   -14 38 45   delta  1
16  form   45 52 -7   delta  -8
17  form   -7 60 13   delta  4
18  form   13 44 -39   delta  -1
19  form   -39 34 18   delta  2
20  form   18 38 -35   delta  -1
21  form   -35 32 21   delta  2
22  form   21 52 -15   delta  -3
23  form   -15 38 42   delta  1
24  form   42 46 -11   delta  -4
25  form   -11 42 50   delta  1
26  form   50 58 -3   delta  -20
27  form   -3 62 10   delta  6
28  form   10 58 -15   delta  -4
29  form   -15 62 2   delta  31
30  form   2 62 -15   delta  -4
31  form   -15 58 10   delta  6
32  form   10 62 -3   delta  -20
33  form   -3 58 50   delta  1
34  form   50 42 -11   delta  -4
35  form   -11 46 42   delta  1
36  form   42 38 -15   delta  -3
37  form   -15 52 21   delta  2
38  form   21 32 -35   delta  -1
39  form   -35 38 18   delta  2
40  form   18 34 -39   delta  -1
41  form   -39 44 13   delta  4
42  form   13 60 -7   delta  -8
43  form   -7 52 45   delta  1
44  form   45 38 -14   delta  -3
45  form   -14 46 33   delta  1
46  form   33 20 -27   delta  -1
47  form   -27 34 26   delta  1
48  form   26 18 -35   delta  -1
49  form   -35 52 9   delta  6
50  form   9 56 -23   delta  -2
51  form   -23 36 29   delta  1
52  form   29 22 -30   delta  -1
53  form   -30 38 21   delta  2
54  form   21 46 -22   delta  -2
55  form   -22 42 25   delta  2
56  form   25 58 -6   delta  -10
57  form   -6 62 5   delta  12
58  form   5 58 -30   delta  -2
59  form   -30 62 1   delta  62
60  form   1 62 -30

 disc   3964
Automorph, written on right of Gram matrix:  
5788591406539787767296194303  361672073709940783423276163010
12055735790331359447442538767  753244210407084073508733597857


 Pell automorph 
379516400906811930638014896080  11947234168218377212415555918097
12055735790331359447442538767  379516400906811930638014896080

Pell unit 
379516400906811930638014896080^2 - 991 * 12055735790331359447442538767^2 = 1 

=========================================

991       991

jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ date
Fri Jul 19 16:34:12 PDT 2013
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$
```