# Finding all solutions of the Pell-type equation $x^2-5y^2 = -4$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations, pell-type-equations

I wanted to solve the equation $x^2-5y^2 = -4$ with $x$ and $y$ integers.

Let $\omega=\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}$ and $A = \mathbb{Z}[\omega]$.
One can reduce the Pell equation to finding the elements of $A$ that have a norm equal to $-4$.

I know that $N(2) = 4$, $N(\omega) = -1$, so that 
for all integer $n$, $N(\pm2\omega^{2n+1}) = -4$.

How can I *prove* that there are no other solution?

I am familiar with Dirichlet's unit theorem, and I have managed (using ad hoc inequalities) to show that $\omega$ is a fundamental unit.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2307710

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And, given the fundamental solutions, all solutions can be found by taking any solution $(x,y)$ and (repeatedly) finding $$  (9x+20 y, 4 x+9y) $$

Note: complete proof is given by working out the Conway topograph for the form $x^2 - 5 y^2$ and noting all occurrences of $x^2 - 5 y^2 = -1$ (to double) and primitive  $x^2 - 5 y^2 = -4.$ I believe i have done exactly that in an earlier question. For example, see [The quadratic diophantine $ k^2 - 1 = 5(m^2 - 1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/340142/how-to-solve-quadratic-diophantine-equation)

Here is the picture; note that you can see the matrix corresponding to the $  (9x+20 y, 4 x+9y) $ formula explicitly. Meanwhile, the river is periodic, one section taken to the next by the map $  (9x+20 y, 4 x+9y). $ Next, all occurrences of $-1$ or $-4$ occur along the river itself, not further away. Finally, it suffices to take (up to $PSL_2 \mathbb Z$) $(-1,1), (1,1), (4,2)$ as the "fundamental" solutions, as $-1$ occurs just once per cycle. Or we could name $ (1,1), (4,2), (11,5)$ and just forget about minus signs entirely.

For $+4,$ we can take $ (2,0), (3,1), (7,3).$

Books with theorems used include Buell, *Binary Quadratic Forms*; Buchmann and Vollmer,  *Binary Quadratic Forms*; Conway, *The Sensual Quadratic Form*.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [Alpertron](http://www.alpertron.com.ar/QUAD.HTM) gives the following fundamental solutions:

$$(x,y)=(\pm 1, \pm 1), (\pm 4, \pm 2)$$

Comment: Sure, and this is consistent with my conjecture, as $2\omega=1+\sqrt5$ and $2\omega^3=4+2\sqrt5$. But how do you prove it?

Comment: The website gives step-by-step justification if you ask for it.