# Are there any integer solutions to $x^2 - (n^2 - 2)y^2 = -1$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I was just wondering if there are any integer solutions to the Diophantine equation:

$x^2 - (n^2 - 2)y^2 = -1 \ \ $  for $n > 2$

I don't think there are any but can't prove why.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell's_equation

Comment: Sorry! It is meant to be $-1$ not $1$!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if $d$ is divisible by a prime $p$ of the form $4k+3$, then the equation $x^2-dy^2\equiv -1$ cannot have a solution, for $x^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$ does not have a solution.

If $n>2$ is odd, then $n^2-2\equiv -1\pmod{4}$, so $n^2-2$ is divisible by a prime of the form $4k+3$.

If $n$ is divisible by $4$, then again $n^2-2$ is divisible by a prime of the form $4k+3$.  But this leaves the possibility $n\equiv 2\pmod{4}$, where $n^2-2$ need not have a prime divisor of the form $4k+3$.

**Remark:** Will Jagy has settled the problem in general, by observing that the continued fraction of $\sqrt{n^2-2}$ has period $4$. (If $\sqrt{d}$ has continued fraction with even period, then the equation $x^2-dy^2=-1$ has no integer solutions.)

There is an approach that does not use properties of continued fractions, but instead uses basic properties of Pell equations.  Note that $x=n^2-1$, $y=n$ is a solution of the Pell equation $x^2-(n^2-2)y^2=1$. If there were solutions of  $x^2-(n^2-2)y^2=-1$, there would be a fundamental solution $(a_0,b_0)$, and $(n^2-1,n)$  would be an "even power" of $(a_0,b_0)$, in the sense that 
$n^2-1+n\sqrt{n^2-2}=(a_0+b_0\sqrt{n^2-2})^{2k}$ for some positive integer $k$. This is not possible, for if $(a_0+b_0\sqrt{n^2-2})^{2k}=a+b\sqrt{n^2-2}$, then $a \ge n^2-1$, and we cannot have equality.

Comment: Hi, Andre. It follows from the continued fraction. I put in $n=6,14.$

Comment: @WillJagy: I did check those two (as you observed, $n=10$ dies since $7$ divides $98$). Maybe the period of the continued fraction can easily be shown to be even in general, but I have not done the calculation.

Comment: @Iyengar: Thank you very much for pointing out the LaTeX error.

Comment: @AndréNicolas : You are always welcome sir.

Comment: @AndréNicolas : Sir my bounty on this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158312/proving-a-statement-regarding-a-diophantine-equation) is going to get expired within 3 days. Do you have any suggestions sir ?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: in simple terms, this follows from the fact that the continued fraction for $\sqrt{n^2 -2}$ has period $4,$ with coefficients
$$ [n-1;1,n-2,1,2n-2]  $$

There are no solutions for
$$ x^2 - (n^2-2)y^2 = -1  $$ with $n>2.$The small values of $ x^2 - (n^2-2)y^2,$ given by continued fractions or by this, the method of neighboring reduced forms, are $$ 1, \, 2, \; 3 - 2 n.   $$

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ 
    jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./Pell
Input n for Pell 
7

0  form   1 4 -3   delta  -1
1  form   -3 2 2   delta  1
2  form   2 2 -3   delta  -1
3  form   -3 4 1   delta  4
4  form   1 4 -3

 disc   28
Automorph, written on right of Gram matrix:  
2  9
3  14


 Pell automorph 
8  21
3  8

Pell unit 
8^2 - 7 * 3^2 = 1 

=========================================
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./Pell
Input n for Pell 
14

0  form   1 6 -5   delta  -1
1  form   -5 4 2   delta  2
2  form   2 4 -5   delta  -1
3  form   -5 6 1   delta  6
4  form   1 6 -5

 disc   56
Automorph, written on right of Gram matrix:  
3  20
4  27


 Pell automorph 
15  56
4  15

Pell unit 
15^2 - 14 * 4^2 = 1 

=========================================
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./Pell
Input n for Pell 
23

0  form   1 8 -7   delta  -1
1  form   -7 6 2   delta  3
2  form   2 6 -7   delta  -1
3  form   -7 8 1   delta  8
4  form   1 8 -7

 disc   92
Automorph, written on right of Gram matrix:  
4  35
5  44


 Pell automorph 
24  115
5  24

Pell unit 
24^2 - 23 * 5^2 = 1 

=========================================
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$
```

Since Andre is asking about $n \equiv 2 \pmod 4$ when $n^2 -2$ may happen to have no prime divisors $q \equiv 3 \pmod 4,$ I have also run $n=6,14.$

```
=========================================
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ 
    jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./Pell
Input n for Pell 
34

0  form   1 10 -9   delta  -1
1  form   -9 8 2   delta  4
2  form   2 8 -9   delta  -1
3  form   -9 10 1   delta  10
4  form   1 10 -9

 disc   136
Automorph, written on right of Gram matrix:  
5  54
6  65


 Pell automorph 
35  204
6  35

Pell unit 
35^2 - 34 * 6^2 = 1 

=========================================
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./Pell
Input n for Pell 
194

0  form   1 26 -25   delta  -1
1  form   -25 24 2   delta  12
2  form   2 24 -25   delta  -1
3  form   -25 26 1   delta  26
4  form   1 26 -25

 disc   776
Automorph, written on right of Gram matrix:  
13  350
14  377


 Pell automorph 
195  2716
14  195

Pell unit 
195^2 - 194 * 14^2 = 1 

=========================================
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$
```

Comment: How is the first one a solution?

Comment: Also $\,\,x=-1\,,\,y=0\,$

Comment: Note that the OP made a mistake in the original post.

Comment: Running low on edits. The first few continued fraction convergents are $$ n-1, \; n, \; \frac{n^2 - n - 1}{n-1}, \; \frac{n^2 - 1}{n}.$$ Note that we have reached the first nontrivial positive Pell solution with the last one, as $$ x = n^2 - 1, \; y = n $$ gives $$ x^2 -(n^2 - 2) y^2 = 1.$$

Comment: Hmmm. I give a pretty good introduction, including how to do the algorithm in detail, at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90406/how-to-detect-when-continued-fractions-period-terminates/90565#90565 and http://mathoverflow.net/questions/22811/upper-bound-of-period-length-of-continued-fraction-representation-of-very-composi/23014#23014

Answer (score 0):

This can be a form of Pell's equation if $\,n^2-2\,$ is not a square, and it always has non-trivial solutions with $\,y>0\,$ by a theorem of Lagrange.

Comment: the OP changed the question.

Comment: Yeah...a little too late.

Comment: Just as a matter of interest $n^2 -2$ is never a square when $n$ is an integer, since for positive integers $x >y$, $x^2 - y^2$ is expressible as a sum of distinct odd numbers.