# When is $991n^2 +1$ a perfect square?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations, congruences, pell-type-equations

What should be the value of $n$ so that the number obtained after adding $1$ to $991$ times its square is itself a perfect square?  Can you please give me a few hints on this topic with a few specific reasons?

Comment: when `n=12055735790331359447442538767`

Comment: Is this about the software *Mathematica* or math in general? At the moment, I would vote for migration to math.SE, unless you provide specific *Mathematica* context.

Comment: also when `n=1008181262620735744167792492163533642911135470182537538260111475016204176230983865302765679861027454092581309875511466063617515681981450574077777701066673093443597760980859827958195535968873238692485090651626582411263121110856835646287364490934750153148422986688525426434604991928802125512669893600` Using the code `FindInstance[991 n^2 + 1 == m^2 && m > 0 && n > 0, {m, n}, Integers, 2]`

Comment: You can see the first solution in https://oeis.org/A154651 and also when $991n^2+1$ is a prime.

Comment: Community moderators: if this was a bad migration please let me know.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1673657/when-is-991n2-1-a-perfect-square

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1673657/when-is-991n2-1-a-perfect-square/1673659?s=4|0.3832#1673659

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1673657/when-is-991n2-1-a-perfect-square/1673659?s=4|0.3436#1673659

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1673657/when-is-991n2-1-a-perfect-square/1703940#1703940

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1673657/when-is-991n2-1-a-perfect-square#autocomment10357731

Comment: Apart from whatever @JasonB. had already said, there will be  solutions to the listed problem

Comment: Apart from whatever @JasonB. had already said now, the other few solutions to the listed problem are (1)n=9150698914859994783783151874415159820056535806397752666720 as well as the following: (2)n=6945680635899069348063079893854789105557565351617874814495165631493551941446359906376433^2=482424794959033003465359432470366998870441530495894964124424636352132271625183897511163064372212178832598048285824010

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1673657/when-is-991n2-1-a-perfect-square#autocomment10357772

Comment: Now @PlatoManiac, you will delete my recent comments, one of which I posted on the current site 60+ mins ago, the other of which I posted on the current site 53 mins ago along with my other few comments, all of which I posted on the current site 8 years ago,it will be very urgent now.

Answer (score 6):

You can just use `Reduce` or `Solve` to find all solutions.

```
res = n /. Solve[991 n^2 + 1 - m^2 == 0 && n > 0 && m > 0, {n, m}, Integers]
```

> ```
> {
>  ConditionalExpression[
>   -(((379516400906811930638014896080 - 12055735790331359447442538767 Sqrt[991])^C[1] - 
>      (379516400906811930638014896080 + 12055735790331359447442538767 Sqrt[991])^C[1])/(2 Sqrt[991])), 
>   C[1] \[Element] Integers && C[1] >= 1]
> }
> ```

You can extract the first few solutions too

```
Join @@ Expand[Table[res /. C[1] -> c, {c, 1, 5}]]
```

> ```
> {
>  12055735790331359447442538767, 
>  9150698914859994783783151874415159820056535806397752666720, 
>  6945680635899069348063079893854789105557565351617874814495165631493551941446359906376433,
>  5271999433569103258723914248134175943728525822653760579284456787639484415276520819628700849418208095077650461959498560,
>  4001620501221794409312976029031442933498062372893574314883667652582151036043020918794933123007401495529956942619504146458469286535007087494712913167
> }
> ```

Here's a nice site that show's you how to solve quadratic bivariate diophantine equations:

https://www.alpertron.com.ar/QUAD.HTM (Though there does seem to be a hand wavy step at that site for your example.)

Also, note that your equation is an instance of [Pell's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation), which is one of the most well known diophantine equations. The wiki link explains how to solve them pretty in depth.

Answer (score 2):

To find all solutions within a range for `n`

```
{Reduce[{991 n^2 + 1 == m^2, 0 < n < 10^100, m > 0}, {n, m}, Integers] // 
  ToRules}

(*  {{n -> 12055735790331359447442538767, 
  m -> 379516400906811930638014896080}, {n -> 
   9150698914859994783783151874415159820056535806397752666720, 
  m -> 288065397114519999215772221121510725946342952839946398732799}, {n -> 
   694568063589906934806307989385478910555756535161787481449516563149355194144\
6359906376433, 
  m -> 21865108547738831347559404499351403341371834338816401962797676457811460\
9092763357330159760}}  *)

Length[%]

(*  3  *)
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to solve $991n^2 +1=m^2$. Write it as $m^2-991n^2=1$ and this is [Pell's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation).

[This applet](http://www.numbertheory.org/php/pell.html) tells us that $$m=379516400906811930638014896080, n=12055735790331359447442538767$$ is the smallest solution.

Pell's equation $x^2-dy^2=1$ is famous for having *very large* [smallest solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation#The_smallest_solution_of_Pell_equations) even for small $d$.

Comment: Try also [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2-991*y%5E2%3D1+in+integers) and http://www.jakebakermaths.org.uk/maths/jshtmlpellsolverbigintegerv10.html.

Answer (score -1):

I am giving you the following equations for which 991n^2+1=m^2 and they are these : (a)12055735790331359447442538767^2=145340765446276487999885076246978166471414204258297880289,now 145340765446276487999885076246978166471414204258297880289*991= 144032698557259999607886110560755362973171476419973199366399 whose successor  144032698557259999607886110560755362973171476419973199366400 is a perfect square and its square root is 379516400906811930638014896080,
(b)9150698914859994783783151874415159820056535806397752666720^2=83735290630419886064759896365549964843256299345531716534246061798413453014599018855005034552161536336522871395558400,now 83735290630419886064759896365549964843256299345531716534246061798413453014599018855005034552161536336522871395558400*991=82981673014746107090177057298260015159666992651421931085437847242227731937467627685309989241192082509494165552998374400 whose successor 8298167301474610709017705729826001515966699265142193108543784724222773
1937467627685309989241192082509494165552998374401 is a perfect square and its square root is 288065397114519999215772221121510725946342952839946398732799
(c)6945680635899069348063079893854789105557565351617874814495165631493551941446359906376433^2=48242479495903300346535943247036699887044153049589496412442463635213227162518389751116306437221217883259804828582401030720561122083475138010369817501016733633284033132297803489,now 4824247949590330034653594324703669988704415304958949641244246363521322
7162518389751116306437221217883259804828582401030720561122083475138010
369817501016733633284033132297803489*991=47808297180440170643417119757813369588060755672143190944730481462496308118055724243356259679286226922310466585125159421444076071984723861768276489143507583030584476834107123257599 whose successor 4780829718044017064341711975781336958806075567214319094473048146249630
8118055724243356259679286226922310466585125159421444076071984723861768
276489143507583030584476834107123257600 is a perfect square and its square root is 2186510854773883134755940449935140334137183433881640196279767645781146
09092763357330159760,I have found these three solutions of n & m through research,

Comment: @Community-Please donot delete my answer as this is the result of my research on Wolfram Mathematica