# Method for solving Diophantine equation $ax^2 + bx + c = y^2$

Tags: diophantine-equations, computational-complexity, pell-type-equations

**How do I solve the Diophantine equation $ax^2 + bx + c = y^2$?**

The approach I have so far is to use the transformation
$$
X = 2ax + b, \\
Y = 2y.
$$

Applying this, we get,

$$X^2 - dY^2 = n,$$

where $$n = b^2 - 4ac \text{ and } d = a.$$

$X^2 - dY^2 = n$ is a Pell equation which may be solved using the method for solving Pell-type equations.

**Questions:**

1. Is there any other method?
2. What is the complexity of the algorithm for finding the solution to the Pell equation?

Comment: Since, as you say, this is a slight transformation of a Pell equation (up to checking some parities), solving this is more or less equivalent to solving a Pell equation, and you can look up all sorts of literature about those.

Comment: Modular method without continued fraction: [link1](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3496844/602207), [link2](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3342764/602207). Method by Norman Wildberger: [link3](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2948392/602207).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128930/whenever-pells-equation-proof-is-solvable-it-has-infinitely-many-solutions/831363#831363
https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1056199_general_pell_equation
https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1049910___4
https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1048216__

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "usual" method is [continued fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation#Fundamental_solution_via_continued_fractions).  This is (asymptotically) slower than $O(p(n))$ for any polynomial $p$.

Using the quadratic sieve and assuming the generalized Riemann hypothesis (described in [L2002]), solutions can be found in time $\exp \left( O(\sqrt{\log n \log \log n}) \right)$, which is still (asymptotically) slower than any polynomial.

There are polynomial time quantum algorithms.[H2007]

[H2007]: Hallgren, Sean (2007), "Polynomial-time quantum algorithms for Pell's equation and the principal ideal problem", Journal of the ACM, 54 (1): 1–19, doi:10.1145/1206035.1206039, S2CID 948064

[L2002]: Lenstra, H. W., Jr. (2002), "[Solving the Pell Equation](http://www.ams.org/notices/200202/fea-lenstra.pdf)" (PDF), Notices of the American Mathematical Society, 49 (2): 182–192, MR 1875156